# Why isn't CDATA protecting my javascript code from the HTML validator?

Tags: javascript, validation, cdata, w3c-validation

I inserted some js code (provided by a third party service) in my webpage and it broke my html validation. How can I fix the problem? CDATA isn't doing the trick.
This is my sample snippet:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"> 
<html> 
<head>
  <title>test</title>
  <script type="text/javascript">
  /*<![CDATA[*/
    document.write('<script src="//sharebutton.net/plugin/sharebutton.php?type=horizontal&u=' + encodeURIComponent(document.location.href) + '"></scr' + 'ipt>');
  /*]]>*/
  </script>
</head>
<body>

  <p>test</p>

</body>
</html>
```

And [here](https://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fandreaconsole.altervista.org%2Fextra%2Ftest.html&charset=%28detect%20automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0) you can find the result of the validator.

Comment: Can you explain to me, why your code looks like XSS-injection?

Comment: The end of that script looks very odd/suspicious `</scr' + 'ipt>'`?

Comment: @Liam — It stops `</script>` being interpreted as the end tag for the actual script element.

Comment: @Mouser — It doesn't look like XSS. This is a fairly standard way to provide a third party hosted script that is aware of what page it was loaded onto.

Comment: Ah, I see. Thanks for the clarification

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`<![CDATA[*` is a feature of XML, not HTML. It is just part of the text content of the script element in HTML terms.

To safely include the string `</script>` in a JavaScript string literal in HTML: Escape the slash:

```
'"><\/script>')
```

Comment: It works llike a charm! Thanks. It's easier when you know what you are doing... It would have taken eons for me to figure out the problem!

Answer (score -4):

I think all that's wrong here is your nested block comment.  Try this instead...

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"> 
    <html> 
    <head>
      <title>test</title>
      <script type="text/javascript">
      /*<![CDATA[
        document.write('<script src="//sharebutton.net/plugin/sharebutton.php?type=horizontal&u=' + encodeURIComponent(document.location.href) + '"></scr' + 'ipt>');
      ]]>*/
      </script>
    </head>
    <body>

      <p>test</p>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: The comment isn't supposed to surround the whole script. The goal is to provide CDATA flags to HTML parsers (except it only works on XML parsers) while commented them out from the JavaScript parser. Commenting out the whole script will just stop it from working in a different way.